# How can access xampp main page?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed XAMPP(7.0.4) for windows 10, control panel works fine, I started Apache, but, when I type "*localhost*" in my browser "Google Chrome" it redirected to *"http://localhost/dashboard/"*

I want to access this page : http://cdn.portableapps.com/xampp.png

when I change the url to "//localhost/xampp/index.php", it tells me:

"**The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.**

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
.."

Also I **can not** access **xampp security page.**

Is there anyone who can help me deal with this? 
Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. I think we deleted the xampp folder from within htdocs.

Comment: If config.inc.php, php.ini, my.ini, and mercury.ini are set up correctly you may be able to live without it anyways, otherwise install a new copy. Make sure you save  your htdocs folder first. Good luck. I hate setting up a Server. Seems like something always goes wrong.

Comment: I've installed version 1.8.3 of xampp. It's working. When I installed newer version, some folders couldnt be installed as you said. :S

Comment: sadly, this what i get, the security page have removed due to some reason , check it here https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=69810&start=15

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to navigate to your custom script:

Add a folder to /htdocs/ in xampp folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\foldername
```

Add a script to the folder

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\foldername\index.php
```

Restart apache in control panel

Navigate to folder/script

```
localhost/foldername/index.php
```

Comment: You likely need to edit your hosts file to have  cdn.portableapps.com point to localhost https://bowerwebsolutions.com/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/ Maybe you can be more specific on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
[image]
[image][2]

Then step - 3

```
localhost/typeyoururl/
```